# Ruby sort array of strings by time value in each string

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, date, time

I have an array of strings like this:

```
strings = [
 "ANT 107 90  Intro to Envrmntl Archaeology   CMWL 101  TTH    01:00PM-02:15PM  Markin       2/15        0      4.00",
 "AMS 210 10  Intro to American Lit II        SMTH 222  TTH    11:30AM-12:45PM  DeProspo,R   0/25        0      4.00",
 "AMS 210 11  Intro to American Lit II        SMTH 222  TTH    01:00PM-02:15PM  DeProspo,R   1/25        0      4.00",
 "AMS 300 10  Toni Morrison                   DALY 107  TTH    10:00AM-11:15AM  Knight      12/20        0      4.00",
 "AMS 394 11  SpTp: Public Opinion Amer Pol   DALY 107  TTH    02:30PM-03:45PM  Cossette     5/16        0      4.00",
 "ANT 105 10  Introduction to Anthropology    CMWL 210  TTH    11:30AM-12:45PM  Lampman      1/25        1      4.00",
 "ANT 107 10  Intro to Envrmntl Archaeology   CMWL 101  TTH    11:30AM-12:45PM  Markin       2/25        0      4.00",
 "ANT 107 90  Intro to Envrmntl Archaeology   CMWL 101  TTH    01:00PM-02:15PM  Markin       2/15        0      4.00",
 "ANT 294 10  SpTp: Queer Anthropology        CMWL 210  TTH    01:00PM-02:15PM  Neely        0/12        1      4.00",
 "ANT 300 10  Language and Culture            CMWL 101  TTH    02:30PM-03:45PM  Neely        1/18        0      4.00",
 "ANT 320 10  Race and Ethnicity              CMWL 101  TTH    10:00AM-11:15AM  Lampman     -4/16        2      4.00",
 "ANT 104 10  Intro to World Music & Ethno    GCA  204  TTH    10:00AM-11:15AM  McCollum, J  0/25        0      4.00",
 "ANT 105 10  Introduction to Anthropology    CMWL 210  TTH    11:30AM-12:45PM  Lampman      1/25        1      4.00",
 "ANT 294 10  SpTp: Queer Anthropology        CMWL 210  TTH    01:00PM-02:15PM  Neely        0/12        1      4.00",
 "ANT 300 10  Language and Culture            CMWL 101  TTH    02:30PM-03:45PM  Neely        1/18        0      4.00",
 "ANT 320 10  Race and Ethnicity              CMWL 101  TTH    10:00AM-11:15AM  Lampman     -4/16        2      4.00",
 "ANT 104 10  Intro to World Music & Ethno    GCA  204  TTH    10:00AM-11:15AM  McCollum, J  0/25        0      4.00",
 "ANT 105 10  Introduction to Anthropology    CMWL 210  TTH    11:30AM-12:45PM  Lampman      1/25        1      4.00",
 "ANT 300 10  Language and Culture            CMWL 101  TTH    02:30PM-03:45PM  Neely        1/18        0      4.00",
 "ANT 320 10  Race and Ethnicity              CMWL 101  TTH    10:00AM-11:15AM  Lampman     -4/16        2      4.00",
 "ANT 104 10  Intro to World Music & Ethno    GCA  204  TTH    10:00AM-11:15AM  McCollum, J  0/25        0      4.00",
 "AMS 210 10  Intro to American Lit II        SMTH 222  TTH    11:30AM-12:45PM  DeProspo,R   0/25        0      4.00",
 "AMS 210 11  Intro to American Lit II        SMTH 222  TTH    01:00PM-02:15PM  DeProspo,R   1/25        0      4.00",
 "AMS 300 10  Toni Morrison                   DALY 107  TTH    10:00AM-11:15AM  Knight      12/20        0      4.00",
 "AMS 394 11  SpTp: Public Opinion Amer Pol   DALY 107  TTH    02:30PM-03:45PM  Cossette     5/16        0      4.00",
 "ANT 104 10  Intro to World Music & Ethno    GCA  204  TTH    10:00AM-11:15AM  McCollum, J  0/25        0      4.00",
 "ANT 294 10  SpTp: Queer Anthropology        CMWL 210  TTH    01:00PM-02:15PM  Neely        0/12        1      4.00",
 "AMS 300 10  Toni Morrison                   DALY 107  TTH    10:00AM-11:15AM  Knight      12/20        0      4.00",
]
```

I want to sort this array by the start time, first value would be `01:00PM` for `ANT 107 90  Intro to Envrmntl Archaeology`. Is there any straight forward way of doing this?

Comment: Is it an array of strings? or an array of arrays containing strings, what's the structure you're working with?

Comment: it is an array of strings with each new line separating different elements of the array

Comment: When posting on Stack Overflow it's worth taking the time to sketch in at least a partial solution. This is just a dump of data.

Comment: You have broken three of the fundamental rules when giving an example. Firstly, you say you say what follows is an array of strings. It is not; it is a pictorial representation of such. It needs to be a valid Ruby object: `["<first line>", "<second line>",..., "<last line>"]`, in part so that readers can cut and paste. Secondly, you should assign a variable to that object (e.g., `strings = [....]`) so that readers can refer to that variable in comments and answers without having to define it. I therefore replaced what you have with what @rablex gave in his/her answer. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Thirdly, examples are to as brief as possible but still make your point. You don't need almost 30 lines; 4 or 5 would be sufficient. Moreover, each line should have been simplified. The first line, for example, could have been, say, `"ANT 107 Intro to Archaeology   01:00PM-02:15PM  Markin       "`.  The method used to sort the rows is the same for the original and simplified example. In short you are requiring everyone who posts a solutions to waste time doing what you should have done in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another alternative using `DateTime`:

```
require 'date'

strings.sort_by! do |item|
  time = item.scan(/(\d{2}:\d{2}(PM|AM))/)
  DateTime.parse(time.first.first).to_time.to_i
end

puts strings
```

Comment: `/(\d{2}:\d{2}(PM|AM))/` could you explain this regex.

Comment: It matches 2 digits (`\d` means 0-9, `{2}` means match twice) followed by a colon, followed by 2 digits followed by PM or AM. The brackets around the whole thing make it return the whole match. So you'll end up with something like `[["01:00PM", "PM"]]` (since scan returns the groups) hence why you need `time.first.first`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick hack approach based on your data. Is not really sorting on time (ignores AM/PM) just by time as a numerical value.

```
strings.sort! { |x,y|
  # split on time delimeter
  s = x.index('-')
  # sort by time as numerical
  x[s-7..s-1] <=> y[s-7..s-1]
}

puts strings
```

outputs:

```
ANT 107 90  Intro to Envrmntl Archaeology   CMWL 101  TTH    01:00PM-02:15PM  Markin       2/15        0      4.00
ANT 294 10  SpTp: Queer Anthropology        CMWL 210  TTH    01:00PM-02:15PM  Neely        0/12        1      4.00
AMS 210 11  Intro to American Lit II        SMTH 222  TTH    01:00PM-02:15PM  DeProspo,R   1/25        0      4.00
ANT 294 10  SpTp: Queer Anthropology        CMWL 210  TTH    01:00PM-02:15PM  Neely        0/12        1      4.00
ANT 294 10  SpTp: Queer Anthropology        CMWL 210  TTH    01:00PM-02:15PM  Neely        0/12        1      4.00
ANT 107 90  Intro to Envrmntl Archaeology   CMWL 101  TTH    01:00PM-02:15PM  Markin       2/15        0      4.00
AMS 210 11  Intro to American Lit II        SMTH 222  TTH    01:00PM-02:15PM  DeProspo,R   1/25        0      4.00
ANT 300 10  Language and Culture            CMWL 101  TTH    02:30PM-03:45PM  Neely        1/18        0      4.00
AMS 394 11  SpTp: Public Opinion Amer Pol   DALY 107  TTH    02:30PM-03:45PM  Cossette     5/16        0      4.00
...
...
```

Comment: This is interesting, but AM and PM does matter here

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
data = <<data.split("\n")
ANT 107 90  Intro to Envrmntl Archaeology   CMWL 101  TTH    01:00PM-02:15PM  Markin       2/15        0      4.00
AMS 210 10  Intro to American Lit II        SMTH 222  TTH    11:30AM-12:45PM  DeProspo,R   0/25        0      4.00
AMS 210 11  Intro to American Lit II        SMTH 222  TTH    01:00PM-02:15PM  DeProspo,R   1/25        0      4.00
AMS 300 10  Toni Morrison                   DALY 107  TTH    10:00AM-11:15AM  Knight      12/20        0      4.00
AMS 394 11  SpTp: Public Opinion Amer Pol   DALY 107  TTH    02:30PM-03:45PM  Cossette     5/16        0      4.00
ANT 105 10  Introduction to Anthropology    CMWL 210  TTH    11:30AM-12:45PM  Lampman      1/25        1      4.00
ANT 107 10  Intro to Envrmntl Archaeology   CMWL 101  TTH    11:30AM-12:45PM  Markin       2/25        0      4.00
ANT 107 90  Intro to Envrmntl Archaeology   CMWL 101  TTH    01:00PM-02:15PM  Markin       2/15        0      4.00
ANT 294 10  SpTp: Queer Anthropology        CMWL 210  TTH    01:00PM-02:15PM  Neely        0/12        1      4.00
ANT 300 10  Language and Culture            CMWL 101  TTH    02:30PM-03:45PM  Neely        1/18        0      4.00
ANT 320 10  Race and Ethnicity              CMWL 101  TTH    10:00AM-11:15AM  Lampman     -4/16        2      4.00
ANT 104 10  Intro to World Music & Ethno    GCA  204  TTH    10:00AM-11:15AM  McCollum, J  0/25        0      4.00
ANT 105 10  Introduction to Anthropology    CMWL 210  TTH    11:30AM-12:45PM  Lampman      1/25        1      4.00
ANT 294 10  SpTp: Queer Anthropology        CMWL 210  TTH    01:00PM-02:15PM  Neely        0/12        1      4.00
ANT 300 10  Language and Culture            CMWL 101  TTH    02:30PM-03:45PM  Neely        1/18        0      4.00
ANT 320 10  Race and Ethnicity              CMWL 101  TTH    10:00AM-11:15AM  Lampman     -4/16        2      4.00
ANT 104 10  Intro to World Music & Ethno    GCA  204  TTH    10:00AM-11:15AM  McCollum, J  0/25        0      4.00
ANT 105 10  Introduction to Anthropology    CMWL 210  TTH    11:30AM-12:45PM  Lampman      1/25        1      4.00
ANT 300 10  Language and Culture            CMWL 101  TTH    02:30PM-03:45PM  Neely        1/18        0      4.00
ANT 320 10  Race and Ethnicity              CMWL 101  TTH    10:00AM-11:15AM  Lampman     -4/16        2      4.00
ANT 104 10  Intro to World Music & Ethno    GCA  204  TTH    10:00AM-11:15AM  McCollum, J  0/25        0      4.00
AMS 210 10  Intro to American Lit II        SMTH 222  TTH    11:30AM-12:45PM  DeProspo,R   0/25        0      4.00
AMS 210 11  Intro to American Lit II        SMTH 222  TTH    01:00PM-02:15PM  DeProspo,R   1/25        0      4.00
AMS 300 10  Toni Morrison                   DALY 107  TTH    10:00AM-11:15AM  Knight      12/20        0      4.00
AMS 394 11  SpTp: Public Opinion Amer Pol   DALY 107  TTH    02:30PM-03:45PM  Cossette     5/16        0      4.00
ANT 104 10  Intro to World Music & Ethno    GCA  204  TTH    10:00AM-11:15AM  McCollum, J  0/25        0      4.00
ANT 294 10  SpTp: Queer Anthropology        CMWL 210  TTH    01:00PM-02:15PM  Neely        0/12        1      4.00
AMS 300 10  Toni Morrison                   DALY 107  TTH    10:00AM-11:15A
data

puts data.sort_by{|x| 
  x =~ /\s(\d\d:\d\d)([AP])M/
  '%s%s' % [$2=='A' ? 0 : 1,$1]
  }
```

The `$2=='A' ? 0 : 1` is not needed with your data, but it is relevant for data like

```
data = <<data.split("\n")
ANT 107 90  Intro to Envrmntl Archaeology   CMWL 101  TTH    01:00PM-02:15PM  Markin       2/15        0      4.00
AMS 210 10  Intro to American Lit II        SMTH 222  TTH    02:00AM-12:45PM  DeProspo,R   0/25        0      4.00
data
```

Comment: In view of my edit to the question you could replace `data` with `strings` and remove your definition of `data`.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [
 "ANT 107 90  Intro to Archaeology   01:00PM-02:15PM  Markin     ",
 "AMS 210 10  Intro to Lit I         11:30AM-12:45PM  DeProspo,R ",
 "AMS 210 11  Intro to Lit II        02:00PM-03:15PM  DeProspo,R ",
 "AMS 300 10  Toni Morrison          10:00AM-11:15AM  Knight     "
]

arr.sort_by { |s| [s[40], s[35,5]] }
  #=> ["AMS 300 10  Toni Morrison          10:00AM-11:15AM  Knight     ",
  #    "AMS 210 10  Intro to Lit I         11:30AM-12:45PM  DeProspo,R ",
  #    "ANT 107 90  Intro to Archaeology   01:00PM-02:15PM  Markin     ",
  #    "AMS 210 11  Intro to Lit II        02:00PM-03:15PM  DeProspo,R "]
```

Notice that if `s = arr.first` then

```
[s[40], s[35,5]]
  #=> ["P", "01:00"]
```

The ordering of arrays used by [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) is explained in the third paragraph of the doc for [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E). The ordering of strings (e.g., comparing `"P"` vs `"A"` or `"01:00"` vs `"01:20"`) is explained in the doc for [String#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E).`["A", "11:30"]` would be sorted before `["P", "01:00"]` because `"A"` precedes `"P"`. Similarly, `["P", "01:00"]` is sorted before `["P", "02:00"]` because the first elements of the two arrays are equal and `"01:00"` precedes `"02:00"`.

One could alternatively write

```
arr.sort_by { |s| s[40] + s[35,5] }
```

Is `s = arr.first` then

```
s[40] + s[35,5]
  #=> "P01:00"
```